# How to reload JCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I am using the [responsive jcarousel plugin](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/cookbook/responsive-carousel.html) and I have a problem. Everything works fine responsive and nice when I load the web, but if I resize the browser window the carousel messes up.

I figured out I should be firing `jcarousel reload method` to make it recalculate the quantity of slides and their sizes. The problem is I cannot make the carousel reload. Please, see code below:

This is what makes my jcarousel responsive(this works fine):

```
 var jcarousel = $('.jcarousel');

    jcarousel.on('jcarousel:reload, jcarousel:create', function () {
        console.log('reloading carousel');
            var carousel = $(this),
            width = carousel.innerWidth();
            cantSlides = 1;
            if (width >= 1600){
                width = width / 4;
                cantSlides = 4;
            }else if (width >= 1200) {
                width = width / 3;
                cantSlides = 3;
            }else if (width >= 800) {
                width = width / 2;
                cantSlides = 2;
            }
            carousel.jcarousel('items').css('width', Math.ceil(width) + 'px');

            $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '-='+cantSlides
            });

            $('.jcarousel-control-next')
            .jcarouselControl({
                target: '+='+cantSlides
            });

        })
```

And this is what is not working:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.jcarousel').jcarousel('reload', {});
});
```

I placed a `console.log` inside the carousel reload,create function. It logs when I press F5 but it does not when I resize the browser window. Why is my reload event not firing?

Thanks!

Comment: try with `animation:slow` for reload

Comment: @dreamweiver still does not work :( No errors are shown in console, but it is not firing.

Comment: Could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

I found where the mistake was!
`jcarousel.on('jcarousel:reload, jcarousel:create', function () {` was wrong, the correct syntax is this: `jcarousel.on('jcarousel:reload jcarousel:create', function () {`, with a space instead of a comma.

Comment: Good,now let's close this  question by accepting the answer